# Excel Formula - Similar to an IF/THEN Count IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, countif

I have a spreadsheet that is the export of an employee Time Clock app.
Some employees clock in and clock out 2 times per day. This is due to lunch
They clock in and clock out before lunch. After lunch they clock in again, and clock out when they are ready to leave for the day.

```
Column A = Employee Name (First Name Last Name)
Column B = Date and Time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM AM/PM)
Column C = Hours (00.000)
```

I am trying to come up with a formula that can be used for GOAL: 
COUNT of SUM of Hours By Employee Name, by DATE.

Is there a way to do this using an excel formula.

I realize I may have to concanotate Column B or use Text to Columns before actually running the formula.

Maybe I can use Slicers or Pivot Tables?

Please let me know the best way to approach this.

I can send the spreadsheet if that is helpful?

Comment: yes, it would be useful if you could post some sample data

Comment: How do I upload a spreadsheet for others to view? Is that Possible?

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to post an image, but can upload an image to a hosting site like imgur.com and link to it, someone with enough reputation will likely come along and post it for you. You can also use http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to generate a table and then add it to your post by editing it

Comment: @user9927197 you can use google drive / onedrive to share the spreadsheet (: